# C - functions that return pointers, how to write efficient code?

Tags: c, pointers, memory

If I had a function defined arbitrarily like:

```
char* myfunction(int, int[]);
```

which, as shown, returns a character pointer. Do you have to write in the calling function something like:

```
char *ptr = myfunction( ... );
```

Or is there a way to use the pointer that is returned by the function without creating *another* pointer to the one returned?

I ask because, given how I described above, you essentially have a pointer returned, and another pointer assigned to that one. Thus, you then have an unused pointer (the one returned by the function) taking up memory.

If there is no way to explicitly use the pointer that is returned, is there a way to assign a new pointer to the returned pointer and free the unused one?

Comment: You mean something like `printf("%c\n", *myfunction(...));`?  That's fine, so long as someone is clearing up the memory that's being pointed to by the pointer.

Comment: Why don't you try compiling to assembler when using an automatic variable on the stack and again in the case where you use the function result directory?

Comment: if your function returns a pointer to a `struct` you can do something like `myfunction()->mystructmember;` This assumes that the function always returns non-NULL.

Comment: What you've forget to mention: does the caller need to call `free()` later? Are there any funny results expected when I call `printf("%s %s\n", f1(this), f1(that));`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pointer is a really small thing. It's just a representation of the address of an object. You shouldn't be concerned about creating extra copies of a pointer (it's like creating an extra int).

```
char* foo() { 
  char* bar;
  // some stuff that mallocs a value and assigns to bar
  return bar;
}

char* x = foo();
```

In the simplified example above, the bar pointer is created on the stack, and the code in the comments points it at some memory in the heap (with a Malloc or something). When the function foo() is evaluated, the value of the pointer (e.g. The address of the memory) is popped off the stack and assigned to x. There is no unused pointer hanging around, it's just been reassigned. The memory that it points to remains exactly where it is and isn't duplicated.

You aren't creating extra copies of the memory that the pointer is pointing to. In fact, that's a large reason to pref pointers, because it involves copying less.

Comment: Agreed about the micro optimisation being generally premature in this case.

Comment: I knew it was extremely small, as you say. I was just wondering. I suppose I was thinking of the worse case scenario. As in, a program that creates a million pointers or something. Now you have a million extra char-size memory slots taken up. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: @sherrellbc The compiler has to store the returned pointer **anywhere** anyway. Most probably `char *p = foo(); if (p) { do_stuff(); }` and `if (foo()) { do_stuff(); }` will translate to ***the exact same assembly code.***

Comment: comments: `(1)` hopefully function `foo()` used `malloc` to dynamically allocate memory for `bar` before returning, otherwise it is likely `foo()` is not returning a valid pointer  `(2)` avoid assigning `*bar` to refer to anything on the stack  `(3)` don't `free(bar)` inside `foo()` function since you are returning `bar`'s address  `(4)` the caller must `free(x)` at some point to avoid a memory leak  `(5)` returning pointers from functions can be tricky in terms of who "owns" the pointer.  Generally better practice for caller to allocate `*x`, pass `x` into foo(), `free(x)` when done.

Answer (score 2):

The pointer that is returned by the function doesn't waste memory as you state. When the function returns, and as soon as the affectation `ptr = myfunction(...);` is done, the returned value doesn't exist anymore in memory.

But to answer your question, yes you can use the returned pointer directly, without a temporary variable. Although it is a rvalue (you can't do `myfunction() = NULL` for example), the location it's pointing to is at your disposal : `*myfunction() = 3` is valid, granted the pointer returned is valid.

I prefer using a temporary variable, as you can reuse the value in 2 or more expressions, and it is far more readable in my opinion.